# Create Dynamic Assembly On New App Domain

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit

I am trying to create a dynamic assembly on a separate app domain as shown here:

```
string webProfilesNamespace = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Profiles.Web.Namespace"];
AssemblyName webAName = new AssemblyName(webProfilesNamespace);
AppDomain webDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("WebDomain");
AssemblyBuilder webAsmBuilder = webDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(webAName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
```

The problem is I keep getting this error when I call `DefineDynamicAssebly`:

> Type 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder' in assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is
>   not marked as serializable.

What do I have to do in order to be able to define dynamic assemblies on a newly created app domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `DefineDynamicAssembly` in the new app domain. Maybe do that using `AppDomainCallback`. I forgot what the method was called.

Comment: The method is named DoCallBack :)

Comment: What a terrible name.

Comment: I keep getting an error saying it can't serialize the class that DoCallBack is being called from.... I tried marking the class as serializable, but that did not seem to help. Is there a reason why the class has to be serializable?

Comment: Yes, the reason is that it must be serialized across app domains. You need to ensure that anything that your delegate references transitively can be serialized.